# Deleting unknown file name with *.exe extension in AutoIT

Tags: autoit, delete-file

I want to delete all files which extension is `.exe`.
For example, there are two files in some directory:

- Something1.exe
- Anything2.exe

How can I detect and then delete them?

Is that possible in AutoIT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [it's possible](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileDelete.htm).

Delete one or more files.

```
FileDelete ( "path" )
```

> **Parameters**
>   *Path* - The path of the file(s) to delete. Wildcards are supported.
>
> **Return Value**
>   *Success:* -  Return 1.
>   *Failure:* - Returns 0 if files are not deleted or do not exist.

Comment: there is another problem encountered: fe. I want to remove all *.exe files except the 'config.exe' or 'start.exe', is that possible two? `:|`

Comment: @Cyclone: Without writing a loop, not just using `FileDelete()`.  However, you could just temporarily rename your `config.exe` and `start.exe` files to names that don't end in `.exe`, do the delete, then rename them back.

Comment: @Cyclone: Use [`FileChangeDir`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileChangeDir.htm) to set your working directory. Then use the example script from [`FileFindNextFile`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileFindNextFile.htm). Use "`*.exe`" as the "File search string" in `FileFindFirstFile` and replace the last MsgBox command with `If Not StringRegExp($file, "(config|start)\.exe") Then FileDelete($file)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <File.au3>

    #include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
    
    Local $aArray = _FileListToArrayRec(@ScriptDir, "*.log", $FLTAR_FILES, $FLTAR_RECUR, $FLTAR_SORT)
    _ArrayDelete($aArray, 0)
    _ArrayDisplay($aArray, "Sorted tree")
    
    For $i in $aArray
        ConsoleWrite(@ScriptDir&"\"&$i&@CRLF)
        FileDelete(@ScriptDir&"\"&$i)
    Next
```

change the second argument with your wildcard.